# Cartesian product of data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, cartesian-product

Trying to get the Cartesian product of two data types into a list:

```
 data X = hello | goodbye | hi 
      deriving (ord, enum, eq, show)
 data Y = hello | goodbye | hi 
      deriving (ord, enum, eq, show)

 compList :: [a]
 compList = [(x, y) | x <- X, y <- Y]
```

Obviously the x <- X etc doesn't work currently and I was just wondering how you guys would go about this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

aside from the casing problem and that you cannot have two data-constructors with the same name here, I think the easiest way is to include `Bounded` then you almost got it:

```
data X = Hello | Goodbye | Hi 
      deriving (Enum, Bounded, Show)

data Y = Hello2 | Goodbye2 | Hi2
       deriving (Enum, Bounded, Show)

compList :: [(X,Y)]
compList = [(x, y) | x <- [minBound..maxBound], y <- [minBound..maxBound]]
```

using `Enum` you can use `[a .. b]` syntax (what you probably already know) and `Bounded` gives you `minBound` and `maxBound`

---

#### output

```
λ> compList
[(Hello,Hello2),(Hello,Goodbye2),(Hello,Hi2),(Goodbye,Hello2),(Goodbye,Goodbye2),(Goodbye,Hi2),(Hi,Hello2),(Hi,Goodbye2),(Hi,Hi2)]
```

---

of course if you don't want to use `Bounded` you can give the limits yourself:

```
data X = Hello | Goodbye | Hi 
      deriving (Enum, Show)

data Y = Hello2 | Goodbye2 | Hi2
       deriving (Enum, Show)

compList :: [(X,Y)]
compList = [(x, y) | x <- [Hello .. Hi], y <- [Hello2 .. Hi2]]
```

of course here this is almost as long as saying `[Hello,Goodbye,Hi]` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can derive Enum and Bounded. This allows you to write:

```
data X = hello | goodbye | hi
  deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

data Y = a | b | c
   deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded)

allX :: [X]
allX = [minBound..maxBound]

allY :: [Y]
allY = [minBound..maxBound]

allXY = [ (x,y) | x <- allX, y <- allY ]
```